# Using babel-plugin-module-resolver with jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I've got `babel-plugin-module-resolver` set up on my project and it works fine, until I run my tests.

I've set up `~/` to point to `./src`.

I've tried adding the following to `package.json` but it still does not work

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "react-native",
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "~": "./src"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [babel-jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/babel-jest) plugin to make jest use babel as a preprocessor.

You can also find an example of this [here](https://github.com/kentcdodds/jest-babel-plugin-module-resolver)